# Script Question regarding finding and renaming a CSV file

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a script that starts off with testing for the existence of a CSV file. If it finds one, rename it to listing.txt.

This is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
if [ -f "*.csv" ];
   then
   cp *.csv listing.txt
fi
```

Comment: What if there are multiple CSV files in the directory you're searching? You can't give them all the same name.

Comment: There will only be one at any given time. At the end, the script will delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code tests for the existence of a file called `*.csv` (literally).  This is why it does not work.  It does that because the `*` is within double quotes.

Using `[ -f *.csv ]` will not work as expected if there are multiple files matching the pattern.  If there are multiple files matching `*.csv`, the `cp` command will additionally not work properly, unless `listing.txt` is the name of a directory.

To rename the *first* of the files matching the filename globbing pattern `*.cvs` in the current directory, do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- *.csv

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ ! -f "$1" ]; do
    shift
done

if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    mv -- "$1" listing.txt
fi
```

This first sets the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, etc., the all names matching `*.csv` in the current directory.  Then it starts looking for the first regular file, or symbolic link to a regular file, among the matched names (the code assumes that the `*.csv` glob *may* expand to directory names etc.).  If a regular file, or a symbolic link to one, is found, it renames that file to `listing.txt`.

In the `zsh` shell:

```
mv -- *.csv(-.[1]) listing.txt
```

This uses a glob modifier for the `*.csv` globbing pattern that returns the first regular file or symbolic link that matches the pattern.

Comment: Great. I will try that. Thanks so much.